# How to make GitHub Actions communicate with each other

Tags: github, github-actions

I am creating a new workflow file using GitHub Actions.

I want to take the outcome of an action and use it as an input to another action. How can I accomplish this?

For instance:
I have an action generating the new version number of my artefact. I would like to use this version number in the commit message when another action is committing the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to previous answer, one can define outputs in the action.yml and set the output within the bash-script: `echo ::set-output name=OUTPUT::"$OUTPUT"`

Steps also have the ability to communicate using the file-system on the runner, but this behaviour is a bit harder to debug...

Answer (score 1):

You can share any data between steps using environment variables. Here is an example:

```yaml
steps:
  - run: echo "::set-env name=TIMEZONE::$(curl https://ipapi.co/timezone)"
  - run: echo "Timezone is ${{ env.TIMEZONE }}."
```

Resource:

https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/github_actions_16_conditionals_with_shared_data.html